# two identity servers (ID3 + 3rd party Saml Id server) with total 7 web apps(SPA, Mvc, api, legacy asp.net etc)

Tags: oauth, openid, saml, identityserver3

we have a good running setup with ID3 and three web apps connected with openId(with external login support). The challenge I am having with the other running setup with 3rd party Saml ID federater supporting 4 web apps. Yeah, here comes the ques: how the two teams(english team & russian team) can work together.

If I am correct Id3 can support both controllers (mvc for forms authentication+api with token authentication) in a single web app where the Id3 can federate token to both apps in single security context(HttpContext). In similar way the Id3 federation service should be able to mix (id3+Saml) after adding the Kentor AuthService(limited saml support). I am moving in my direction.

Any help/idea would be great welcome.

Answer (score 1):

idrv3 can support any number of IDP.

The answer depends on how you propose to join everything together - diagram?

Kentor is only a client-side SAML stack. It won't work upstream of idsrv3.

You might have to use something like Auth0 e.g.

idsrv3 --> WS-Fed --> Auth0 --> SAML --> other IDP.

What other protocols does the other IDP support?

Comment: thanks for answer; based your blog (http://nzpcmad.blogspot.in/2015/12/identityserver-power-of-extensibility.html), I decided to plug kentor as you said ----I've used it in a number of projects to essentially extend ADFS by federating ADFS and idsrv3 and then "altering" and "extending" on the upstream and downstream paths.----

Comment: ok, so moving forward as you asked diagram: (which I need to check with customer) and other protocols(apart from Saml) is: OpenId Connect.

Comment: as an example: one of 3rd party Idp server app is https://staging.schoox.com which needs to be integrated (SSO + Saml) with our existing asp.net apps (connected with Id3)

Comment: You can plug ADFS into the above instead of Auth0.

Comment: how about using id4 + Rsk Saml plugin ( released 3 days back  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rsk.IdentityServer4.Saml/ ) ? yeah .net core would make things harder.